# Convert list to list of tuples with repeated value of item in each tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a few N-dimensional arrays as below. How can I convert these arrays into tuples?

```
num = ['1' '2']
letter1 = ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f']
letter2 = ['aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'dd' 'ee' 'ff']
```

The result I want is:

```
tuple1 = [(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(1,d),(1,e),(1,f)]
tuple2 = [(2,aa),(2,bb),(2,cc),(2,dd),(2,ee),(2,ff)]
```

I have

```
tuple1 = tuple(num[0], letter1)
tuple2 = tuple(num[1], letter2)
```

But I got an error of `TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

What would be your approach? Any methods would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `tuple1 = (num[0], letter1)`?

Comment: Try `itertools.product` and/or `zip` with extension.

Comment: @Graipher, if I remove `tuple`, it returned `('1', array(['a', 'b',
       'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
      dtype=object))`

Comment: Yes (as expected). It was meant to show why you get a `TypeError` with that approach (`tuple` takes an iterable and returns a tuple, it does not take the elements of the tuple).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with [**`itertools.repeat`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to achieve this as:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> num = ['1', '2']
>>> letter1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

>>> tuple1 = list(zip(repeat(num[0]), letter1))
>>> tuple1
[('1', 'a'), ('1', 'b'), ('1', 'c'), ('1', 'd'), ('1', 'e'), ('1', 'f')]
```

***PS:*** Note the commas `,` between elements in the above lists. Strings separated without comma are treated as a single string.

---

Inspired from the above answer, here's the *list comprehension* version of the solution to get `tuple1` and `tuple2` in a single go:

```
letter2 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff'] # rest of the variables same as the above solution

tuple1, tuple2 = [list(zip(repeat(a), b)) for a, b in zip(num, (letter1, letter2))]
```

where these variables will hold the below lists as values:

```
>>> tuple1
[('1', 'a'), ('1', 'b'), ('1', 'c'), ('1', 'd'), ('1', 'e'), ('1', 'f')]
>>> tuple2
[('2', 'aa'), ('2', 'bb'), ('2', 'cc'), ('2', 'dd'), ('2', 'ee'), ('2', 'ff')]
```

Comment: and it doesn't create extra lists. Everything is done with iterables. Welcome back Moinuddin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iter` and `next`:

```
num = ['1', '2']
num = iter(num)
letter1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
letter2 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff']
tuple1, tuple2 = [list(zip(i, [next(num)]*len(i))) for i in [letter1, letter2]]
```

Output:

```
[('a', '1'), ('b', '1'), ('c', '1'), ('d', '1'), ('e', '1'), ('f', '1')]
[('aa', '2'), ('bb', '2'), ('cc', '2'), ('dd', '2'), ('ee', '2'), ('ff', '2')]
```

Without `iter`:

```
tuple1, tuple2 = [[(i, h) for i in c] for c, h in zip([letter1, letter2], ['1', '2'])]
```

Comment: that's why you should always test your answers :)

Comment: `[next(num)]*len(i)` works but I think something better can be done with `itertools.repeat`: `itertools.repeat(next(num),i)`: it avoids creating an extra list.

Comment: and you can even forget about limiting with `i` since `zip` stops on the shortest iterable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre agreed; however, MoinuddinQuadri's answer already offers a great solution with `itertools.repeat`, and I thought that plain `zip` with `next` would demonstrate a possibility not relying on builtin libraries

Comment: you're right, sometimes it's better to get back to basics.

Answer (score 1):

Some good answers already but I'll share an alternative using a list comprehension. It looks like a bit more code, but will work for larger lengths of `nums` and `lists` (as long as they are the same length as each other still):

```
letter1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
letter2 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff']
nums = [1, 2]

lists = [letter1, letter2]
tuples = [[(i, x) for x in l] for i, l in zip(nums, lists)]

tuple1, tuple2 = tuples
```

Results:

```
In [1]: tuple1
Out[1]: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'e'), (1, 'f')]

In [2]: tuple2
Out[2]: [(2, 'aa'), (2, 'bb'), (2, 'cc'), (2, 'dd'), (2, 'ee'), (2, 'ff')]
```

Comment: I should take note on your method as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Already there are good answers, I just want to give you hint you can tweak your logic a little

```
num = ['1','2']
letter1 = ['a','b' ,'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
letter2 = ['aa' ,'bb', 'cc', 'dd' ,'ee' ,'ff']
tuple1 = tuple(zip(*[[int(num[0])]*len(letter1),letter1]))
tuple2 = tuple(zip(*[[int(num[1])]*len(letter2), letter2]))

print(tuple1)
print(tuple2)
```

output:

```
((1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'e'), (1, 'f'))
((2, 'aa'), (2, 'bb'), (2, 'cc'), (2, 'dd'), (2, 'ee'), (2, 'ff'))
```

Comment: Ohh I see what you're doing here. I can use `zip` and `len` to define the numbers of elements in a tuple too. Great!